Showing PDP Pricing Details for B2B e-commerce
I am working on designing a Product detail page for a B2B e-commerce website.
Need some inputs on how to show pricing. For example - 1 item cost is $5. However, the product can be ordered in batch of 200 and this would be default quantity set. I was wondering if subtotal that is $5 * 200 should be shown in Product page only. OR should I keep it at cart?

Does this answer your question? Total price on the product page before "Add To Cart" button, why not?
